# not getting any output from my letter count program

Tags: c++

I'm working on program that counts letters in a piece of text, I can't seem to get it to work. Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string inputxt;
    cout << "enter txt:\n";
    getline(cin, inputxt);

    char charcheck[ ]={'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};
    int charsize=sizeof(charcheck)/sizeof(char); 
    int count[charsize];
    cout << charsize;

    for (int i=0; i==inputxt.length(); i++){
        for(int a=0; a==charsize; a++){
            if (inputxt[i]==charcheck[a])
                ++count[a];
        }
    }

    for (int b=0; b==charsize; b++){
        cout << "number of " << charcheck[charsize] << ": " << count[charsize];
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Please note I have not put in all the characters to check the text against. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `for` loops, you're using `==` instead of `<`. For example:

```
for (int i=0; i==inputxt.length(); i++)
```

should be:

```
for (int i=0; i < inputxt.length(); i++)
```

Comment: it's interesting how much a single comment can tell about a person.

Comment: The funny part is, it doesn't even solve the other `for` loops which have exactly the same problem. Notwithstanding the "can't be arsed to explain why" side, mentioning that every single `for` loop in the code is affected would have been the bare minimum, IMHO.

Comment: I don't want to argue with you all day, but if you read my answer, I did say "loops" and "for example".

Comment: Hmm right, I somehow missed that plural. My bad. Wasn't very obvious though. However I still stand by the "can't be arsed to explain" part which @Karoly evidenced. Not that it's hard to explain, just look at my answer. And the most amazing part is, I'm not even trying to draw votes to my answer, I'm just trying to make yours better, if you can believe it.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i=0; i==inputxt.length(); i++){
```

The `for` construct takes 3 parameters:

- initialization
- continuation condition (and not termination condition like you did). read it as a `while ...`
- loop action (aka. afterthought)

In other words, `for (INIT; CONTINUATION; AFTERTHOUGHT) { BODY }` is directly translated as:

```
INIT;
while (CONTINUATION) { BODY; AFTERTHOUGHT; }
```

Reverse your middle condition, it should be `i!=inputxt.length()`. The same applies to every other `for` loops.